# IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1: How do I view the minimum SDK of my Android project

Tags: android, intellij-idea

It has been a while since I have touched this project. I remember when I created it with the project creation wizard, I was asked for a minimum SDK level (or perhaps a target SDK level). Where do I go in the IDE to view and change this level?

I sort of expected the generated code to contain this information in the AndroidManifest.xml file, where it could be easily changed, however it does not seem to be there.

Comment: Can you check the `build.gradle` file inside you app directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is defined in the build.gradle file of the main module(it is named as 'app' if you had not changed) of your project:

> {YourProjectName}/app/build.gradle

the value which `minSdkVersion` stated inside `defaultConfig` block of `android` is exactly what you want!

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I had missed that there was another build.gradle file in the project.